# how to count no.of rows in char data type column

Tags: mysql

my table is

```
date       value       name
may02       22          s1
may03                   s1
may04       34          s2
may05       35          s2
may06                   s3
may07       12          s3
may08       22          s3
```

Value is in char data type
my query is

```
select count(*) as count_value  from my_table group by name;
```

am getting

```
name       count_value
s1           2
s2           2
s3           3
```

but i need

```
name       count_value
s1           1
s2           2
s3           2
```

blank rows should be eliminated ,  plz help me

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
select name, count(*) as count_value  from my_table where length(value) > 0 group by name;
```

Here you have a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/813714/2) sample.

The condition can also be for null values

```
value is not null
```

or if you have, i don't know...spaces? in the value column, something like

```
length(trim(value)) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks @avi , one more help plzz .. what if i have a name is s4 and all the values are blank , then result should be "0" . how we can get

Comment: @suri5913 check this other fiddle for this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36224/5

Comment: Glad to help. Also it would be appreciated to mark this as the correct answer.